# recommended ways of splitting train/validation/test in time series in neural networks

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, train-test-split

for time series using neural networks with 500000 samples I am looking for tips for recommended percentage of spliting samples into train/validation/test and intervals of splitting. I absolutely am not looking for cross-validation answers because my model takes so much time to train.

## percentage

for dataset of lengths of 10,000, 100,000 and 500,000(my case) what are recommended percentages for splitting train and test specifically for time series(30/70 or 98,2 etc)?

## interval splitting

assuming we have chosen 70/20/10 percentage. so is it better to split samples to `train=1-70 val=71-90 test=91-100` or its better to choose intervals i.e. 20 then split (for 100 sample example would be like) `train=1-14,21-34,...,81-94 val=15-18,35-38,...,95-98, test=19-20,39-40,...,99-100`. is there any recommendation for this sort of intervals for splitting?

Comment: this question is closed for wring reasons, the splitting data to train/test is not cross validation.  the answers of these post also imply that, in cross validation we use multiple models but i want to use one model, some answers are there but they re not complete. because they still talking about cross-validation.

Comment: at least if you think answer already exists refer me to better ones

Comment: To get your question reopened, please edit it in a way that distinguishes it from the apparent duplicates.

Comment: @whuber I just re-edited it.

Comment: There are many similar posts, for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453386/working-with-time-series-data-splitting-the-dataset-and-putting-the-model-into  and [this stored google search](site:https://stats.stackexchange.com train-test splitting for time series data?)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Hi again I have same problem. and the reason I didn't ask to reopen it before is that I hate and irritating arguments here. so please reconsider, reopening my question. all suggested duplicates are either about the cross-validation which I had clearly stated that Im not looking for that or either about the model predictions which are not neural nets, mostly with low sample data. but now again I have to deal with this problem so I decided not to ask for reopening.

Comment: so I read [https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=split%20train%20validation%20time%20series%20-cross] but except 4 in which my question was not answered, all others werent relevant.

Comment: I mean I read all of `split train validation time series -cross` searches and now I just ask to reopen it. just to be clear.

Comment: The edited question is dissimilar from the initial set of duplicates, but is duplicated by other questions. This Meta thread gives some tips for how to search CV. https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/faq-best-practices-for-searching-cv